# Passing class type as a parameter in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, types

In my app, I have a Kotlin object that performs database queries. It also saves the data it got from the database to a hashmap named Cache.

Currently, this is the function for getting a specific document from a collection (aka table).

```kotlin
private val CACHE: HashMap<Collection, HashMap<String, Any>>

fun <T> getItemFromCollection(id: String, collection: Collection, onSuccess: (T) -> Unit) {
     // First check if the item is in the cache
     if(CACHE[collection]!!.containsKey(id)) {

         onSuccess.invoke(CACHE[collection]!![id]!! as T)
         return
     }
     // If it is not in the cache, get it from the database
     .....
}
```

This solution is flawed. Since every collection holds only one data type (for example, "users" collection only holds User classes) , I should not be needed to give the getItemFromCollection function a type - it should know what type it needs to return because of the specified collection.

So if I accidently write

```kotlin
  getItemFromCollection<OtherClass>(user_id, Collection.USERS, {...})
```

I will get an error, because the USERS collection only holds User objects, not OtherClass objects.

What I want to do is give every collection a type, then use that type in the getItem fuction. For this, my Collection enum class looks like this:

```kotlin
enum class Collection(val path: String, val type: Class<*>) {
    USERS("users", User::class.java),
    ITEMS("items", Item::class.java)
}
```

But I do not know how to use this type in the getItem function instead of T.

My desired result is something like this:

```kotlin
fun getItemFromCollection(id: String, collection: Collection, onSuccess: (collection.type) -> Unit) {
     // First check if the item is in the cache
     if(CACHE[collection]!!.containsKey(id)) {

         onSuccess.invoke(CACHE[collection]!![id]!! as collection.type)
         return
     }
     // If it is not in the cache, get it from the database
     .....
}
```

But `onSuccess: (collection.type) -> Unit` and `... as collection.type` do not work

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this approach:

```
sealed class Collection<T>(val path: String)

object USERS : Collection<User>("users")
object ITEMS : Collection<Item>("item")

private val CACHE: HashMap<Collection<*>, HashMap<String, Any>>

fun <T> getItemFromCollection(id: String, collection: Collection<T>, onSuccess: (T) -> Unit) { ... }
```

You could also change it to make `getItemFromCollection` a member of `Collection`. See also [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/enum-class-with-type-parameters/1633) and [this solution (linked from there)](https://whatheco.de/2020/05/05/list-of-strongly-typed-objects-acting-like-enum-in-kotlin/).

> thanks! One problem I have with this solution is creating the cache hashmap... In the pervious solution I used `for(coll in Collection) { CACHE[coll] = .... }` but now, I cannot loop through all the collection objects.. Any ideas?

Option 1: just create the list explicitly:

```
sealed class Collection<T>(val path: String) {
    companion object {
        val ALL = listOf(USERS, ITEMS)
    }
}

for (coll in Collection.ALL) {
    ...
}
```

Option 2: register collections in their constructor

```
sealed class Collection<T>(val path: String) {
    companion object {
        val _ALL = mutableListOf<Collection<*>>
        val ALL: List<Collection<*>>
            get() = _ALL
    }

    init {
        _ALL.add(this)
    }
}

for (coll in Collection.ALL) {
    ...
}
```

Option 2:

Comment: thanks! One problem I have with this solution is creating the cache hashmap... In the pervious solution I used ` for(coll in Collection) { CACHE[coll] = .... } ` but now, I cannot loop through all the collection objects.. Any ideas?